# css absolute position on top of another element

Tags: jquery, css

I'm making an html game (no canvas) where players can click image links to do abilities. Abilities then go on cooldown for a set number of seconds. To visually show this cooldown I dynamically create a div tag that is semi-transparent and the same size as the ability images that has the text centered that shows how many seconds remain on the cooldown. I then get the position of the clicked ability image link and position this div at the same location minus the document scrollTop() (because I read that somewhere but this isn't making a difference with or without it currently). The problem is the div doesn't line up vertically. The top left corner is about 1/2 way down the actual image link and I'm not sure why. Any ideas?

```
// the ability image link click event
$(".action").click(function (e) {
    // get the position of the clicked ability image link
    var position = $(this).offset();

    // when I dynamically create the div element here is the css I use
    .css({ "position":"absolute", "top":(position.top - $(document).scrollTop()), "left":position.left, "width":"66px", "height":"66px", "line-height":"66px", "background-color":"rgba(125, 125, 125, 0.75)", "text-align":"center", "vertical-align":"middle", "font-size":"30px", "color":"red" })
}
```

I didn't show the entire append() of the div tag because it would just clutter things up. The .css() part is how the div is defined and I use the top position of the clicked image link as the div's top position but it ends up 1/2 way below the actual image link.

Here are the "relevant" parts of the html. Below is the main body.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
        <!--Actions-->
        <div id="divActionRow" class="row" style="margin-top: 0px;">
            <div id="divPlayerActions" class="col-md-6 text-center">
                <a href="#" class="action" data-cd="5000" data-cast="1000" data-oncooldown="false" id="Cripple"> <img src="/Content/cripple.png"> </a>
                <a href="#" class="action" data-cd="8000" data-cast="2000" data-oncooldown="false" id="GroundSlam"> <img src="/Content/ground_slam.png"> </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!--This is where we dynamically hold the cd divs-->
    <div id="divCDHolders">
       <!--When a cd is active this is what it looks like-->
        <div id="Cripple_cd_value" style="position: absolute; top: 448px; left: 181.5px; width: 66px; height: 66px; line-height: 66px; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; font-size: 30px; color: red; background-color: rgba(125, 125, 125, 0.74902);">2</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: can you show what the html looks like?

Comment: It's rather large, but I'll post the relevant parts.

Comment: Provide a demo that replicates problem. Also  define the expected result.

Comment: just need the part with the timer element

Comment: Have you got margins, paddings or borders in your body element ? Because JQuery is telling this : _jQuery does not support getting the offset coordinates of hidden elements or accounting for borders, margins, or padding set on the body element._

Comment: Ah Ko2r that might be it. Let me give that a try.

Comment: Margins was the reason. That sucks. I can hardcode this but if I ever change the margins there is no way I'll remember to change this. Getting the divs above margin values would work but if I ever add more divs I'll never remember to include those. Would be nice to be able to get all top margins above this div tag.

Comment: Why you need the offset and all that position why don't you just append the element inside ? and make an overlay give me a few minutes I'm making an example

Comment: I've never done an overlay before but sounds promising if it can help me not have to deal with absolute positioning because when the page gets resized this div gets messed up.

Comment: Check the answer maybe a good way to go :D let me know if it is helpfull

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be helpfull, I don't know why are you handle offset positions to make an overlay since you can make the overlay be inside the element and use `absolute` relative to the clicked parent. Check this Snippet:

```js
function overl () {
  var overlay = '<div class="overlay">10</div>';
  $(this).append(overlay);
  var ov = $(this).find('.overlay');
  ov.fadeIn('fast');
  timer(ov);
  $(this).off('click',overl);
}
function timer($el) {
  var sec = $el.text();
  var timer = setInterval(function() { 
   $el.text(--sec);
   if (sec == 0) {
      $el.fadeOut('1000',function(){
        $el.remove();
      });
     $el.parent().on('click',overl);
     clearInterval(timer);
   } 
  }, 1000);
}
$(".action").on('click',overl);
```

```css
.action {
  display:inline-block;
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  font-size: 45px;
  line-height: 70px;
  background: red;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 10px;
  position: relative;
  font-family: 'verdana';
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all .3s linear;
  overflow:hidden;
  margin:10px;
}
.overlay {
  display:none;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background:rgba(0,0,0,.6);
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  z-index:10;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="action">A</div>
<div class="action">B</div>
<div class="action">C</div>
```

Comment: This looks brilliant! I'll get it going here shortly and let you know how it looks.

Comment: 100% great! This worked like a charm and I'll be using this technique in other areas. Thank you so much!

Comment: @user441521 glad to help u mate